# Can't Pass View Model to View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting an error on Return View(viewModel) that says, "'View' is a type and cannot be used as an expression."  How can I fix this?

```
Function ShowFeed() As ActionResult

    Dim feedUrl = "somefeedurl"
    Dim feed As SyndicationFeed = GetFeed(feedUrl)

    ' build a view model
    Dim viewModel = New RssModel()
    viewModel.Title = feed.Title.ToString
    viewModel.Description = feed.Description.ToString
    viewModel.Link = feed.Links.ToString

    Return View(viewModel)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `View()` function is defined in the `Controller` class.
This error would occur if your class does not inherit `Controller`.

Comment: Good answer.  I didn't realize.  Thanks.